# Dancer : how to share data and waiting response between 2 POST without blocking

Tags: perl, scalability, high-availability, dancer, poe

I have a [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) server written in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [dancer](/questions/tagged/dancer) on a VM, this is the workflow :

- customers POST some [json](/questions/tagged/json) stuff in `/post_wait` route : the POST should waiting the business processing to return the result
- the request is processed by another VMs (communication is processed by [POE + IKC](http://poe.perl.org/))
- the report should be returned by `/report` route to the customer identified with the session id by the `REST` server

**DANCER CODE : (that's what I tried so far)**

```
package var;
use Data::Dumper;
use Dancer ':syntax';
use JSON::XS;

my $session = {};

# curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"id":22}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/post_wait
post '/post_wait' => sub {
    my $json = request->body;
    my $h = decode_json $json;
    my $id = $h->{id};
    until (exists $session->{$id}->{report}) {
        sleep 1;
        print STDERR ".";
    }

    return Dumper $session;
};

# curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"foobar":"xxxx"}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/report
post '/report' => sub {
    my $json = request->body;
    my $h = decode_json $json;
    my $id = $h->{id};
    $session->{$id}->{report} = $h;
    return "OK\n";
};

true;
```

**The problem is that this code hangs, because I sleep the parent process.**

Maybe I should use :

- rewrite that with [POE-Component-Server-REST](https://github.com/jstebens/POE-Component-Server-REST.git) ?
- [Dancer::Plugin::Async](http://search.cpan.org/~mstplbg/Dancer-Plugin-Async-0.001/lib/Dancer/Plugin/Async.pm) module ? but can I avoid using this ? (there's some [technical restrictions](http://search.cpan.org/~mstplbg/Dancer-Plugin-Async-0.001/lib/Dancer/Plugin/Async.pm#PROBLEMS))...
- another script as a subprocess ?
- a database like [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) queue using `BLPOP` to dequeue ? (that needs some subprocess code around)
- [Dancer::Session](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer%3a%3aSession) ?
- `fork()` ?
- Threads ? (I guess no)

My information system should be scalable and in [high-availability](/questions/tagged/high-availability) mode.

**What is the best practice to do what I want ?**

Answer (score 2):

You need some kind of seesion tracking. Use Dancer::Session for that.

And you need to do some 'asynchronus', may be fork().

Then you can start the business process by calling

```
# curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"id":22}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/post_wait
```

where the process is forked and the pid is stored in the session.

Then you can call

```
# curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"foobar":"xxxx"}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/report
```

get the pid from your session (if you have one) and check if the process is still running or not.